# Spark REPL gives an error when starting

Tags: apache-spark

I got pre-built Spark 1.4.1 and I'm running HDP 2.6. when I run spark-shell it gives me an error message as follows. Is this because I'm missing a jar file ?

```
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/WebApplicationException
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI.<init>(SparkUI.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI$.create(SparkUI.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI$.createLiveUI(SparkUI.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:440)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.createSparkContext(SparkILoop.scala:1017)
    at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:9)
    at $iwC.<init>(<console>:18)
    at <init>(<console>:20)
    at .<init>(<console>:24)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1338)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoopInit.scala:123)
```

What the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message indicates javax.ws.rs API jar file is missing from your classpath. You can go to Maven repository and download that jar file and put that in you classpath. javax.ws.rs is the Java API for RESTful web services.

Maven repository:
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs

Comment: I'm pretty sure pre-built Apache Spark comes with all required jars included. Downloading arbitrary jars from the Maven repository sounds like bad advice. Perhaps the wrong pre-built release was used?